# How can I encrypt a string in a portable class library without using PCLContrib?

Tags: c#, encryption, portable-class-library

I am building a portable library targeting `Windows 8.1`. I need to encrypt a password to send it across an http connection. The problem is that `System.Security.Cryptography` is not available in portable libraries.

The only solution that I've been able to find is the `PCL Contrib`, but it seems far too bulky to add that to my project. I was also getting some runtime exceptions in `PCL Contrib` that I couldn't resolve.

I am sure that there has to be a simple solution out there, but I haven't been able to find any that doesn't use `System.Security.Cryptography`. Does anyone know of a simple to use encryption that can be used in a portable library?

Comment: Just use a `https` url. Custom crypto is much too hard to get right. In particular authenticating the server is problematic since you'd either create a PKI or hardcode the server's public key. And even if you solve that part, the rest of the crypto is still tricky. And you'd need to protect the session token you get back after a login. In short you'd need to reinvent SSL.

Comment: @CodesInChaos OK, but what if the concerned data are passwords, and that you must login users which passwords are encrypted in the database ?

Comment: @LoulG. *Encrypting* passwords is rarely a good choice (password manages being an exception). In transit the password should be protected with TLS/HTTPS. When storing passwords a user uses to authenticate themselves to your site, you need to store password hashes (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt,...) not encrypted passwords.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thank you for pointing me at the difference between encrypting and hashing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [PCLCrypto](http://nuget.org/packages/pclcrypto). It offers WinRT-like APIs for cryptography, but it works on all the modern platforms.